# How do I add a css class to the last line of a song using the first <strong> and the last <strong>

Tags: css

How do I add a `css` class to the last line of a strong to the first  and the last `<strong>` in a sentence ?

```
<p class="blue">first</p><strong><li class ="apples">apples and</li></strong>
   <strong><li class ="bananas"> bananas</li></strong>.<br>
</p>
```

Comment: It's not clear what your question is, and you've got some pretty invalid code there (`li` inside `strong` etc.) You already have added classes there, although there shouldn't be a gap between `class` and `=`.

Comment: Your HTML structure is not right